# Title of contextMenuItem based on selected element

Tags: android

I need to change the title of some contextMenuItems based on selected elements. I need to check if element ID is empty. If it is empty I need to show changed title of an item (menu_title_1). Otherwise there should be a standard text displayed (menu_title_2).

Please, find my current code below.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
  {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);          
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.listview, menu);
  }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
  {
     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     final int position = info.position;
     final int index = bd.size()-position-1;
     final BDItem bdItem = bd.get(index); 

     MenuItem item_1 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_1);
     // Here is the problem: it does not change the title 
     if(bdItem.getID().equals(""))
       item_1.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_title_1));
     else
       item_1.setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_title_2));   

      switch(item.getItemId()) 
        {
           case R.id.menu_1:
           ...
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fix it earlier but now I solved the problem. I had to edit onCreateContextMenu and add one boolean flag checking ID. That's it...